# When inserting Unicode data in ODBC application, how to determine the encoding in which it should be

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, odbc

I have a generic ODBC application reading and writing data via ODBC to some db(can be ms sql, mysql or anything else). The received and sent data can be Unicode. I'm using SQL_C_WCHAR for my bindings in this case.
So I have two questions here:

1. Can I determine the encoding in which the data came from the ODBC data source?
2. In which encoding should I send data to the ODBC data source? I'm running parameterised insert statement for this purpose.

My researched showed that some data sources have connection options to set the encoding, but I want to write a generic application working with anything.
Couldn't find any ODBC option telling me the encoding of the data source. Is there something like that? ODBC docs just say use SQL_C_WCHAR. Is SQL_C_WCHAR for UTF-16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and both Microsoft docs and unixodbc docs seem to point out that ODBC only supports UCS-2. So I think all the data sent or received needs to be UCS-2 encoded.